# SQL Server (2016) not using indexes with parametric queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, sql-server-2016

I'm having a performance issue in an application.
I isolated the query that it's causing the issue and is a parametric query.
The query is this query (generated by NHibernate)

```
declare @p8 as varchar(4000);
set @p8 = 'AT0703%';
SELECT sum(Movimenti.Importo)
FROM Movimenti
WHERE (IDConto LIKE @p8)
```

This query results in a table scan of table Movimenti.
Movimenti.IDConto is a varchar(15)

Changing the query in this way

```
declare @p8 as varchar(4000);
set @p8 = 'AT0703%';
SELECT sum(Movimenti.Importo)
FROM Movimenti
WHERE (IDConto LIKE 'AT0703%')
```

the index is used.

I tryed to insert

```
option (optimize for unknown)
```

and

```
option (optimize for (@p8 unknown))
```

at the end of the query but they did not change the result.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you post the table definition along with the indexes and approximate row counts?

Answer (score 1):

Use `OPTIMIZE FOR (@p8 = 'AT%')` so SQL Server will use the example pattern to decide that it can/should use the index. LIKE conditions that don't start with `%` can use the index.

For more in-depth info, e.g. see this article:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1354/optimize-parameter-driven-queries-with-sql-server-optimize-for-hint/

I don't know however if you can get NHibernate to supply that hint.

Comment: This works, thanks! Now the problem is how to inject this in NHibernate

Comment: You may use an [interceptor](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html) for this. Derive from `EmptyInterceptor`, override `OnPrepareStatement` and return your modified SQL statement. Inject it in your session when opening it or configure it globally.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @p8 as varchar(4000);
declare @sql as nvarchar(500)
set @p8 = 'AT0703%';
set @sql= 'SELECT sum(Movimenti.Importo)
FROM Movimenti
WHERE (IDConto LIKE ''' + @p8 + ''')'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this, but you can! Your second query is sargable, while your first is probably not, try doing this

```
WHERE (IDConto LIKE @p8 + '%')
```